# How do you propose a project with the forum funding system?

Tags: forum-funding-system

The Forum Funding system is a way of funding Monero projects. Its the way the GUI was funded, for example.

How do you set up a project to use the forum funding system?

Answer (score 7):

One way would be to ask the devs on freenode.org IRC in #monero or #monero-dev , dEBRUYNE should be able to help anyone out with lodging a forum funding bounty.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what ferretinjapan said, there is also a sticky [here](https://forum.getmonero.org/7/open-tasks/2379/forum-funding-system-ffs-sticky).

To quote:

> ### Funding, work start, payments
>
> 1. The project can begin before it's fully funded
> 2. Devs
>      can be paid for milestone completion before it's fully funded
> 3. If the dev disappears, no problem, someone else can pick up from
>      their last milestone
> 4. If the milestones are sufficiently
>      small the dev doesn't have to go 6 months without pay
>
> ### Ideal FFS Workflow
>
> 1. An idea is presented in the **IDEAS** thread. A
>      discussion occurs regarding whether the idea should be developed.
> 2. A developer (who either presented the idea, or saw the idea and
>      realizes they can develop it) pitches their proposal to develop the
>      idea in the **OPEN TASKS** section. At a minimum, this
>      pitch should include
>
> **What** - describe the idea and how you plan to
>   develop it
>  **Who** - who are you? Why do you think
>   you can develop it, and why should the Monero community believe you
>   can?
>  **Why** - Why do you want to develop this? 
>   
>   **The Proposal and Milestones** - It is difficult to
>   describe how each proposal should be broken down into milestones, but
>   only you (the developer) knows how long things can take, and knows how
>   to break the task apart.
>  **Expiration** - Make it
>   apparent that a time limit exists for the proposal. If the project is
>   abandoned, funds will eventually be re-appropriated at the discretion
>   of the core developers. At the minimum, development should start
>   coding "soon" after the funding target has been met in order to avoid
>   re-appropriation.
>
> 1. The community discusses the proposal. The proposal is
>      amended, etc. Eventually the community approves, and the proposal is
>      moved to **FUNDING REQUIRED** by a moderator. Here,
>      funding occurs. People may or may not post that they have contributed.
>      It is not necessary to post your contributions, though it is
>      fine.
> 2. Once fully funded, or development begins, the thread is
>      moved to the **WORK IN PROGRESS* thread, where the developer is
>      expected to provide some kind of activity report.