# MoneyBit GUI compared with "official" GUI

Tags: development, monero-wallet-gui, third-party-wallets

How MoneyBit GUI [now in development](https://github.com/moneybit/moneybit/releases/tag/v0.0.1-alpha) compare with the [official GUI](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core) being worked on by Monero developers?

Will they ultimately support the same operating systems? Are they both completely open source? How do the current and planned features compare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [MoneroBit author](https://github.com/moneybit/moneybit/releases/tag/v0.0.1-alpha), Athan Clark the [primary differences](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5b7tqx/moneybit_alpha_released_for_winlin/d9oloh0/) between MoneyBit and the official QT wallet are:

> - the core dev's GUI will always be more secure than mine.
> - mine is portable to mobile and alternative platforms fairly easily, and feel more modern than something like electrum. It's also capable of being used as a personal web wallet for internal (or external) networks.
> - Mine is written with functional languages, and I wanted to showcase how they can be used to write correct software rapidly. I've already found a few quirks about monero-wallet-cli that in my eyes shouldn't need to exist because I work at a higher level. This project is also something like a proposition to use strongly-typed functional programming languages like Haskell and Elm rather than C++ and JavaScript.

MoneyBit is an independent project without [official support](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5b7tqx/moneybit_alpha_released_for_winlin/d9oloh0/) from the Monero [core team](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1024/136):

> I haven't gotten a blessing from /u/fluffyponyza, nor have I spoken with the core devs about my project to get their approval. The folks on the IRC channel have so far been very appreciative and interested, but that's just speculation. I don't want to step on anyone's toes, and would very much appreciate a "cease and desist" if my project conflicts with the intentions of Monero. But so far I haven't gotten any bad news, but also no good news either. I'm not sure where I stand with them.

Currently Athan Clark is seeking community input on his [development proposal](https://forum.getmonero.org/6/ideas/86993/moneybit-gui) and hopes to raise Monero via the [Forum Funding System](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1654/136) to fund continued development and support of MoneyBit.